# Ideal Experience in Buddhism

Tags: meditation, consciousness, mind-states

Sometimes, I tell myself that a moment wherein I'm devoid of craving, ignorance and aversion is a moment inherently good. I tell myself that if I remove the addictive (and aversive) states within myself , then the right choices within my experience will naturally be made.

So, with the example of social media -- which is addictive for me -- I cannot easily pay mindfulness while doing this activity. However, I view *every* other moment free of affliction as naturally and effortlessly conducive to mindfulness. While doing almost anything that is not afflicted in terms of mental state, mindfulness and curiosity towards experience leads to diverse virtuous results.

Oddly, however, I do not get attached to such virtuous experiences, but return to addictive and pleasurable states. It's like an irony: what is detrimental is naturally addictive and what is wise and virtuous more difficult.

QUESTION 1: Is this view of a 'normal' affliction-free state -- i.e. *not* a meditative absorption or compassion filled state -- as virtuous correct? Just normal awareness?

QUESTION 2: Wouldn't virtuous states, perhaps in time, become addictive in themselves? For now, they are more akin to equanimity, whereas I'm neither drawn or averse to them. Or, would they remain like equanimity?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Eggman,

One starts to get free of addiction simply by keeping Silas: abstain, if there is no real penetration to right view (stress, cause, cessation, path).

It is pointless to try again and again a "short-cut". And there is no such as gaining world and Nibbana together. All undertakings to build equanimity around the cause without removing it, lead to even bigger unpleasant results.

[Do the work to be done](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/23356/buddhism-and-procrastination)! and [keep precepts](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/23214/the-bane-of-social-media).

It has it's cause, it's reason, why one falls in bad realms, becomes a [hungry ghost](http://www.freesangha.com/forums/practice-tools/googlyana-a-dharma-practcice-approach-at-internet-realm/msg46833/#msg46833).

If caught there, in the realm of hungry ghost, in internet: Use the practice of **[Mindfulness practice and meditation in Googlyana](http://www.freesangha.com/forums/practice-tools/googlyana-a-dharma-practcice-approach-at-internet-realm/msg46779/#msg46779)**, starting with [Silas](http://www.freesangha.com/forums/practice-tools/googlyana-a-dharma-practcice-approach-at-internet-realm/msg46791/#msg46791).

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma, not meant for commercial purpose or other kinds of low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange]*